# Is is possible to add the data into echart box that appear when mouse-on in bar chart

Tags: echarts

[whitebox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OOaUS.png)

The sun withboard box. May i ask that how to append the data and display after search engine. Thankyou.

Comment: Yes, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64442517/echarts-show-additional-info-in-tooltip/64456091

Comment: Thanks for info. I already find another way to do what i want.

Comment: It's the same way.

Answer (score 0):

The way to insert the additional data into tooltip:

**Declare formatter**

```
formatter: function (params) { //params can get the data needed like series name
   //params is to get the corresponding data that belong to the pointer
   // var index_ds = params[0].dataIndex (Can use this code to get the index of dataset which is the index where the data come from)
   //Declare a variable to display the data
   let additional = "Additional Data"
   //If want add a new line just like 
   additional += "xxxxx"
}
```

The output will be like this:
==============================
Additional Data
xxxxx
==============================